# Looping back login system

Tags: python

```
account_number = [741852, 963852, 789456]
account_pin    = [4152, 6352, 7485]
account_balance = [1000, 2000, 3000]
account_username = ["Mike", "James", "Leeroy"]

account_number_login = int(input("Enter Account Number:"))
if(account_number_login == account_number[0]):
print("Hello " + account_username[0])
account_pin_login = int(input("Enter Account Pin:"))
if(account_pin_login == account_pin[0]):
    print("Welcome to DC Bank!")
    print(" [1] - Withdraw \n [2] - Deposit \n [3] - Balance 
 Inquiry \n [4] - Exit")



else:
print("Incorrect Account Number, try again.")
account_number_login = int(input("Enter Account Number:"))
```

hi guys Im new to Python. I know in C there is GOTO to loopback on your code. but else isnt returning back. is there GOTO equivalent in PYTHON thanks much appreciated

Comment: You may find this question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/1258041

Answer (score 0):

Use continue that should work if it doesn't ill look into it more